# Solana bootstrap-validator cannot run as expected when create a local cluster

Tags: solana-test-validator, local-cluster

I follow the instructions of Benchmark a Cluster (https://docs.solana.com/cluster/bench-tps). After I executed this line: `NDEBUG=1 ./multinode-demo/bootstrap-validator.sh`, according to the documentation: Wait a few seconds for the server to initialize. It will print "leader ready..." but my reality is that it’s running unstoppable, the console is full of INFO messages scrolling up rapidly and would not stop after an hour or even longer. Anybody can tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behavior! The line right before that says:

> Now start the bootstrap validator in a separate shell:

It does take some time, but the validator starts up and should operate normally in that shell. All of the logs that you see are related to normal validator logs.

You need to leave that running in its own shell while you get the rest of your cluster and bench-tps going.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But when I later try to spin up some additional validators in separate shells using the command: `NDEBUG=1 ./multinode-demo/validator-x.sh`, the new validators can't start success with an error: `Error: unable to confirm transaction. This can happen in situations such as transaction expiration and insufficient fee-payer funds`. Do you know how to solve this problem?